# Qt parse string of undefined size from a binary data stream

Tags: qt, binaryfiles, endianness

I have a binary data stream which contains data that should be interpreted as a Qstring. Starting from the third byte. Here is how the package is generated (on a client).

```
QByteArray package;
package.append( QByteArray::fromHex("0002") );  // First two bytes
package.append( "filename.txt" );               // String of undefined size
package.append( QByteArray::fromHex("00"));     // End of string
```

The decoding is done on a different machine (server). I would like to get a `Qstring` of value `"filename.txt"` from the `QByteArray package` without relying on the size of the string (since the server doesn't have that information) but on the string terminator `00`. How can this be achieved?

Since this decoding will be done on a different machine, how should the raw data be generated on the client to avoid problems with endianess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the `QByteArray` in a [`QDataStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdatastream.html) so you can specify the endianess explicitly and make use of the stream operators

```
QByteArray package;
QDataStream stream(package, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream.setByteOrder( QDataStream::BigEndian);
stream << static_cast<quint16>(0x0002);  // First two bytes
stream << "filename.txt";               // String of undefined size
// no need to write terminating 0 because data stream will prepend length
```

then you can read in the other direction:

```
QByteArray package;
QDataStream stream(package, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream.setByteOrder( QDataStream::BigEndian);
quint16 id;
stream >> id;  // First two bytes
char* filename;
stream >> filename; // String of undefined size
QString file = QString.fromLatin1(filename);
delete[] filename; //cleanup
```

or you can pass a QString to the stream in the first place and not need to deal with the char array:

```
QByteArray package;
QDataStream stream(package, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream.setByteOrder( QDataStream::BigEndian);
stream << static_cast<quint16>(0x0002);  // First two bytes
stream << QStringLiteral("filename.txt"); // String of undefined size
```

note that this will write in utf16 meaning it is unicode enabled

the serialization format is documented at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/datastreamformat.html

Comment: I need the terminating 0 because it's in the standard specification. The question arose from writing an tftp client. Which means the underlying raw binary must be in the form `2byte int, n byte string, 1 byte 0 terminator`

Comment: ah then you should still use a data stream but then use writeRawData on the latin1 encoded string